# How to push data to specific sub-array in an empty 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to setup a 2-d array, which should receive values at specific sub-arrays. I created my array with:

> myArray= Array(100).fill([])

Now, let's say I want to push a value to say sub-array number 40

I'm doing this like that:

> myArray[40].push("myValue")

I would expect the value to be pushed only to the myArray[40] instead it is pushed as the first element of every of the hundred sub-arrays.

I searched for the solution for quite some time, but I still have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill` will push the same value to each element, not a copy of it. That's fine when it's a number or string or something else immutable. But now each copy is a reference to the same object.

There are a number of ways to fix this.  Here's one (switched to ten elements for demonstration):

```js
const myArray = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => [])

myArray[4].push('myValue')

console.log(myArray)
```